# Can I add content before post content without using the_content filter

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, the-content

I am adding filter to add embed before post content, but don't want add to other places where called apply_filters("the_content").

**So i need add embed before(after) post content without "the_content" filter hook.**

```
add_filter('the_content', 'embed_on_post');
```

Comment: Can you please give some more idea on this. Are you using custom theme?

Comment: No, I am writing plugin, and my problem is add embed before(after) post content, and not use the_content filter, you have alternative way please help

Comment: Ok so you mean to add the content of function before post content right? Probably Not possible

Comment: Why can't you use the `the_content` filter? There are ways to limit which uses of the filter the function is applied to. You'd just need to tell us which places you do or don't want to apply the filter.

Comment: I want filter only post(custom post) content, but not any other content filtered by 'the_content'.

Comment: maybe you need to try a hook loop_start https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/loop_start/